# CSS - fa fa icons styling

Tags: css, icons

Is there any way to style fa fa icons if it is active? 
For example buttons:

```
button:active {
   color: white;
}
```

Is there any way to style icons like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using like this

```
.noo-social a .fa-twitter{
    background:#5dd7fc;
    border-color:#5dd7fc
}
.noo-social a .fa-twitter:hover{
    color:#5dd7fc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For buttons, you can make something like that:

```
button:active > i.fa {
   color: white;
}
```

Comment: Strange, it works for me...can you please create a jsfiddle or a codepen?

Comment: Just a second Sir, I'll do it in a minute.

Comment: https://codepen.io/crniivukdevme/pen/xxbpErG here it is. Please help!

Comment: The problem is that you didn't add the font-awesome .min.css link. Try to add the following line inside the `<head>` section of your HTML page: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Comment: I add and when i hove with my cursor at the icon it shows yellow(that's my active color) but after i press and active my button it's stay the same, white.

Comment: Please help, it's just a little thing but pain in the head

Answer (score 0):

Link up this css in your code
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css